# Performance / capacity statistics for web2py?

Tags: python, performance, scalability, web2py

I'm trying to understand the overall performance & scalability of web2py.

Of course this is a very challenging question since performance & scalability are so highly dependent on specific implementation details, hardware, DB design -- every app is different.

Any numbers?  Or even rules of thumb?

I'll be doing full-on scalability testing at some point but don't know what to expect.  Any info you can share that would help with a rough sizing discussion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The bottle neck is always database.**

From my perspective web2py can do a lot of load balancing just because you define database with each request, so you can have db1, db2 and a function that selects which to use. This is plenty good because the most severe damages to performance come from database.

There has been benchmarks which go arround Django performance. Since Django is regarded as quite fast I would not worry to much. The other bottleneck that may come up is models which are loaded on each request. First you can disable migrations which means it will not validate database everytime (should speed things up) and recently Bruno has [showed the modelless mechanism converting them to modules which are loaded explicite.](http://movu.ca/demo/article/show/11/model-less-apps-using-data-models-and-modules-in-web2py)

Comment: As a side note. Scalability today is non-issue up to a certain point. And if you reach scalability problems with your app you ought to have a lot of money on hand to solve them ;]